# java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException

Tags: java, security, azure, ssl

**Azure java SDK** gives ->
**java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target**

```
    ApplicationTokenCredentials credentials = new ApplicationTokenCredentials(options.getClientId(), options.getTenantId(),   options.getClientSecret(), AzureEnvironment.AZURE);

    subscriptionIds.forEach((subscriptionId)->{
        Azure azure = Azure.authenticate(credentials).withSubscription(subscriptionId);
        ResourceGroups resourceGroups = azure.resourceGroups();
        for(ResourceGroup resourceGroup : resourceGroups.list()){
            for(VirtualMachine virtualMachine : azure.virtualMachines().listByGroup(resourceGroup.name())){
                logger.info(virtualMachine.name());
            }
        }
    });
```

I get this error when **for(ResourceGroup resourceGroup : resourceGroups.list())** is executed.
Looking on the net, i added the certificate of management.azure.com in keystore, but that also didn't worked.
Looks like azure establish the connection that's why ResourceGroups are not empty. But don't know why it gives the error later.

Answer (score 0):

Just per my experience, please make sure that the Java security policy files for Unlimited Cryptography are added for that specific version of Java. If not, please follow the steps below to install the Java Cryptography Extension (JCE) Unlimited Strength Jurisdiction Policy Files, which are required to use PGP encryption and may be required by some connectors.

1. Download the files and instructions for [Java 7](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jce-7-download-432124.html) or [Java 8](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jce8-download-2133166.html).
2. Locate the `<JAVA_HOME>\jre\lib\security` directory for the Java instance that the Atom is using. For example, this location might be: `C:\Program Files\Java\jre8\lib\security`.
3. Remove the following .jar files from this directory: local_policy.jar and US_export_policy.jar.
4. Replace these two files with the .jar files included in the JCE Unlimited Strength Jurisdiction Policy Files download.
5. Try to run your code again for checking the issue whether still exists.

Comment: The issue still persists and it is random. It comes up sometimes and doesn't comes up other times